# jQuery .trigger() not firing on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, triggers, custom-events

I am triggering an event on document when a function executes. It's working fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer (Version 11). Here is my code

```
function getBgUrl(el) {
    if (typeof el !== "undefined" || el !== null) {
        var bg = "";
        if (el.currentStyle) { // IE
            bg = el.currentStyle.backgroundImage;
        } else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) { // Firefox
            bg = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "").backgroundImage;
        } else { // try and get inline style
            bg = el.style.backgroundImage;
        }
        return bg.replace(/url\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)/i, "$1");
    }
}

if ( jQuery('#wcp_body').length ) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = getBgUrl(document.getElementById('wcp_body'));
    image.onload = function (event) {
        //jQuery(document).trigger('bgimageloaded');
        jQuery.event.trigger({type: "bgimageloaded" });
    };
}
```

And, then on document ready..

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    $(document).on('bgimageloaded', function() {
        console.log( 'BG Image Loaded' );
    });

});
```

The code above actually gets the background image associated with an element and fires the custom event when the image is loaded. I am not getting why this is not working only in IE11.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: try reading this article, maybe it helps you
 https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893254/JavaScript-Triggering-Event-Manually-in-Internet-E

Answer (score 0):

I think you will set timeOut for trigger.

setTimeout(function(){

//jQuery(document).trigger('bgimageloaded');

```
jQuery.event.trigger({type: "bgimageloaded" });
```

}, 10);